# How to run a function just one time

Tags: android

I need to run a function only once (when it's night, change the image of the imageview) and when I use it in oncreate(), it runs every time I start the 
activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                startAnim();
    }
}

private void startAnim(){
    Date dateNow=new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String night=String.format("%tF",dateNow)+" 19:00:00";
    try {
        Date dateNight=sdf.parse(night);
        if(dateNow.after(dateNight)){
             DisplayMetrics metric = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metric);
            int width = metric.widthPixels;  // 屏幕宽度（像素）
            int height = metric.heightPixels;  // 屏幕高度（像素）
            RotateAnimation ra=new RotateAnimation(0,100,width/2,height/2-80);
            ra.setDuration(4000);
            sunMoon.startAnimation(ra);
              } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: everytime when i start the activity ,it shows the animation ,and i don't know  what to do if i just want it shows when the first time i start it in night every day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either a file or store in a Shared Preference. Example for a save method:

```
private void saveLastRanTime(String key, long lastRunTime) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong(key, lastRunTime); // Store the key somewhere instead of passing in each time
    editor.apply();
}
```

Example check:

```
private boolean wasLastRunToday(String keyOfPreference) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long lastRanAt = prefs.getLong(keyOfPreference, -1); // Save key somewhere..
    if (lastRanAt == -1) { // In the event it was never saved before.
       return false;
    }

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(lastRanAt);
    int dayLastRanAt = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int today = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    return today == dayLastRanAt;
}
```

Which would make your startAnim() method look more like:

```
private void startAnim() {
    if (wasLastRunToday("LAST_ANIMIATION_RUNTIME")) {
        return;
    }

    Date dateNow=new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String night=String.format("%tF",dateNow)+" 19:00:00";
    try {
        Date dateNight=sdf.parse(night);
        if(dateNow.after(dateNight)) {
             DisplayMetrics metric = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metric);
            int width = metric.widthPixels;  // 屏幕宽度（像素）
            int height = metric.heightPixels;  // 屏幕高度（像素）
            RotateAnimation ra=new RotateAnimation(0,100,width/2,height/2-80);
            ra.setDuration(4000);
            sunMoon.startAnimation(ra);
            saveLastRanTime("LAST_ANIMIATION_RUNTIME", dateNow.getTime());
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Record the time of your last time running `startAnim()` in a file. Read this file when you start the activity to decide run `startAnim()` or not.